# Create a new folder in sharepoint layouts

Tags: c#-4.0, sharepoint

I need to keep some data/files inside the layouts folder. My SharePoint project is "MyProject"
Hence the directory structure includes

"C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\LAYOUTS\MyProject"

Now I need to programmatically create a new folder called "Data". But I get "Access Denied" error.

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate
  {
String path = SPUtility.GetGenericSetupPath(String.Empty) + "TEMPLATE\\LAYOUTS\\MyProject\\Data";
bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
if (!IsExists)
  System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);// Access denied!
 });
```

Can anyone tell me why I am getting the access denied ? even though I have wrapped my code inside RunWithElevatedPrivileges?

Answer (score 0):

I've tried you code and work well.

There should be something with Window Folder security settings. On my folder I have next users with read/write permissions:

1. Creator owner - special permissions
2. System - Full control
3. WSS_ADMIN_WPG - All but full control and special permissions
4. Current user (farm admin) - Full control

If nothing helps try to add everyone in read/write access temporary! just to check if it is really security issue!

Hope it helps,

Andrew